# Powershell: Extract value between pattern from a LDIF file

Tags: .net, regex, powershell, regex-group

I'm working my way around the Regex and I'm tasked to write a script to extract specific text between a search pattern on a LDIF and I'm running into some issues. The LDIF we have from is in OpenLDAP format so the file we have is

```
dn: cn=user1,ou=department,o=company,c=root
changetype: add
givenName: Givenname1
sn: SN1
Country: Cn1
userCertificate;binary:: lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3
City: City1

dn: cn=user3,ou=department3,o=company,c=root
changetype: add
givenName: Givenname3
sn: SN3
customdn: cn=user3,ou=department3,o=company,c=root
userCertificate;binary:: lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3
Country: Cn3
City: City3

dn: cn=user2,ou=department,o=company,c=root
changetype: add
givenName: Givenname2
sn: SN2
customdn: cn=user2,ou=department,o=company,c=root
userCertificate;binary:: lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf
 89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl;aiorgpnsg;n\vbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh
 U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3
Country: Cn1
City: City1
```

The file lines are seperated by Line breaks (CRLF). So, I'm trying to extract the text only for User3 with the following pattern which seem to give me blank file.

```
$RegexPattern = "`r`ndn: cn=User3(.*?)`r`n`r`n"
$result = [regex]::match($inputfile,$RegexPattern).Groups[1].Value
```

if I change the capture pattern from to (.*), I get all text from after the first match. Pretty sure I'm missing something but just not able to see what is that I'm missing. Can someone kindly help?

Edit: Adding some additional info about custom DN too. The reason for including a CRLF in the search string for dn: is because there is also a custom DN on the user object which is a duplicate of the dn attribute for backward compatiblities. I've updated the example LDIF entry above with this attribute.
Edit 2: Wiktor's regex nearly works until the code stumbles upon the userCertificate attribute which where multiple attributes are split only with a LF than a CR+LF seen everywhere else.

Comment: How do you get `$inputfile`? BTW, your regex won't work even if you read the file correctly and add the `(?s)` inline modifier at the start of the pattern, if the match is expected also at the start of the string.

Comment: My Input definition is 
`$inputfile = Get-Content .\input.ldif`

I've tried both with and without `-Raw` switches

Comment: Ok, you must use `$inputfile = Get-Content .\input.ldif -Raw`. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, make sure you read the whole file into a variable:

```
$inputfile = Get-Content .\input.ldif -Raw
```

Then, you need a regex like

```
$RegexPattern = '(?mi)^dn: cn=User3[^\r\n]*(?:\r?\n[^\r\n]+)*'
$result = [regex]::match($inputfile,$RegexPattern).Value
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fmi%29%5edn%3a+cn%3dUser3%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d*%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%29*&i=dn%3a+cn%3duser1%2cou%3ddepartment%2co%3dcompany%2cc%3droot%0d%0achangetype%3a+add%0d%0agivenName%3a+Givenname1%0d%0asn%3a+SN1%0d%0aCountry%3a+Cn1%0d%0auserCertificate%3bbinary%3a%3a+lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf%0d%0a89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl%3baiorgpnsg%3bn%5cvbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh%0d%0a+U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3%0d%0aCity%3a+City1%0d%0a%0d%0adn%3a+cn%3duser3%2cou%3ddepartment3%2co%3dcompany%2cc%3droot%0d%0achangetype%3a+add%0d%0agivenName%3a+Givenname3%0d%0asn%3a+SN3%0d%0acustomdn%3a+cn%3duser3%2cou%3ddepartment3%2co%3dcompany%2cc%3droot%0d%0auserCertificate%3bbinary%3a%3a+lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf%0d%0a89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl%3baiorgpnsg%3bn%5cvbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh%0d%0aU0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf%0d%0a89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl%3baiorgpnsg%3bn%5cvbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh%0d%0aU0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf%0d%0a89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl%3baiorgpnsg%3bn%5cvbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh%0d%0aU0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf%0d%0a89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl%3baiorgpnsg%3bn%5cvbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh%0d%0a+U0hBMjU2MB4XDTE5MDYwNTA3%0d%0aCountry%3a+Cn3%0d%0aCity%3a+City3%0d%0a%0d%0adn%3a+cn%3duser2%2cou%3ddepartment%2co%3dcompany%2cc%3droot%0d%0achangetype%3a+add%0d%0agivenName%3a+Givenname2%0d%0asn%3a+SN2%0d%0acustomdn%3a+cn%3duser2%2cou%3ddepartment%2co%3dcompany%2cc%3droot%0d%0auserCertificate%3bbinary%3a%3a+lowhjsefnasdvonidfb8943th54ebghyLHFUn9894y9bKalkbjsf%0d%0a+89ehgvpnoLNGPOVNnl%3baiorgpnsg%3bn%5cvbubGB*gpbeoabgpiobrgaragop08hgnaoergn9r0agnh%0d%0a%0d%0aCountry%3a+Cn1%0d%0aCity%3a+City1)

**Details**

- `(?mi)` - case insensitive matching ON and the multiline behavior is ON, too
- `^` - start of a line
- `dn: cn=User3` - a literal text
- `[^\r\n]*` - 0+ chars other than CR and LF
- `(?:\r?\n[^\r\n]+)*` - 0+ occurrences of CRLF/LF and then 1+ chars other than CR and LF (so, any non-empty lines below the string above).

Comment: This is likely going to work, except, there is just one another problem!
Certain legacy applications doesn't seem to know how to query/use the DN of the object so for backwards compatibility, we duplicate that value to a customdn attribute. I'm assuming I have to add an additional filter at the beginning?

Comment: @mutukrp If you mean you need to find either `dn` or `customdn`, you may use an alternation, `'(?mi)^(?:dn|customdn): cn=User3([^\r\n]*(?:\r\n[^\r\n]+)*)'`. Feel free to update the question with these details.

Comment: Thanks. That nearly worked. Except, two problems. the dn: cn=user3 is chopped off in the results. And one of the attributes, usercertificate is a multiline string value which is separated only with a LF instead of CR+LF. This whole regex is going over my head now. :(

Comment: @mutukrp Look, you are accessing Group 1 value with your `[regex]::match($inputfile,$RegexPattern).Groups[1].Value`. If you need the whole match, use `[regex]::match($inputfile,$RegexPattern).Value`. My regex still works for the string even if it contains a multiline attribute. The `[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n[^\r\n]+)*` part matches all up to the double line break or end of string.

Comment: That helped with the stripping dn: user3 but the script still get's stuck at userCertificate attribute which is a multi-string with each lines split only by LF instead of CR+LF. I think `(?:\r\n[^\r\n]+)*` looks for a "rough" match instead of exact match. Can you rephrase that explanation in your answer a bit more please? what is the 0+ and 1+ in your answer means?

Comment: @mutukrp 0+ = *zero or more times*, 1+ - *one or more times*. Try making CR optional, `(?:\r?\n[^\r\n]+)*`

Comment: That one worked! Thanks a lot for your help. Would you like to update your answer and I'll mark that as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to read the file as single string, split on 2 (or more) NewLines and use a `Where-Object` clause to get the textblock starting with `dn: cn=user3`.

```
(Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\openLDAP.ldif' -Raw) -split '(\r?\n){2,}' | 
 Where-Object { $_.Trim() -match "^dn: cn=user3" }
```

Result:

```
dn: cn=user3,ou=department3,o=company,c=root
changetype: add
givenName: Givenname3
sn: SN3
Country: Cn3
City: City3
```